# MSTSC Return value in Powershell/ RDP Automation

Tags: powershell, mstsc

I would like to know the values which are returned by invoking mstsc.exe in PowerShell. I am writing a PowerShell script to automate RDP check. However, I am unable to identify the servers for which the RDP is failing? I have tried using try-catch and if-else, however it is not helping.

Comment: `mstsc` is not a console application.  AFAIK, it does not return any codes.

Comment: You can check to see if a connection is available by seeing if port 3389 accepts connections